# Is there a way to install GNOME 3.12 in Ubuntu 14.04 without destroying Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome

For theme development purposes, I'd like to have both GNOME 3.12 and Unity installed at the same time, and without the inconvenience of a virtual machine/dual boot. I know that the project Neon ppa for KDE 5 installs in it's own folder in /opt so as not to mess with existing KDE installations, and installing Trinity does the same. Is there any way to install GNOME 3.12 so that all of it's files are in it's own folder in /opt, or a different install setup so that Unity won't be destroyed? Thanks for any input.

Comment: So I would have to compile all of it from source?

Comment: If you're using the staging ppa watchout, there may be conflicting dependency issues with unity for a little while untill the package versions sinc back up.